# IE tries to download pages as binary when they have compilation errors

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, git

I have an asp.net mvc3 Razor app being developed in VS2010 using Git for source control.  Since I moved to a new machine, compilation errors in my cshtml, instead of getting a nice informative yellow screen of death, I get the following behavior:  in Chrome:  nonesense characters; in IE:  message that IE can't download the page.  This happens even if I deploy the code to another machine.  It seems like both browsers are treating whatever is being returned as binary, but I'm not sure why.

Has anyone seen this before?

Thanks!

Comment: what are the compilation errors ?

Comment: you may have error on the compression on gzip, or you predefine the web page size for the compression and after the error this size can not change because is on header, and the gzip decompression of the error page fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you enabled gzip compression. Take a look at the [following blog post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/02/ASPNET-GZip-Encoding-Caveats) for more details.